# Is there a Python function to make all possible substititutions between two equal length strings?

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance, character-replacement

I am trying to make all possible substitutions between a reference and a test sequence. The sequences will always be the same length and the goal is to substitute Test characters with those of Ref.

```
Ref= "AAAAAAAAA"
Test="AAATAATTA"
```

Desired output:

```
AAATAATTA, AAATAAAAA,  AAATAATAA,  AAATAATTA,  AAAAAATTA,  AAAAAATAA,  AAAAAAATA
```

Comment: Does this mean that the i-th character in the new_string can be either `Ref[i]` or `Tests[i]`, for each i in the length of the string? Thus creating `2^len -1` possible new_strings, where `len  = len(Ref)`?  However, you only want these substitutions when Ref[i] ~= Test[i]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` for this if you `zip` the two strings together (turning them into a set of 2-tuples for `product` to find combinations of).  You then probably want to uniquify them in a set.  All together it looks like this:

```
>>> {''.join(t) for t in product(*zip(Ref, Test))}
{'AAAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAATAA', 'AAAAAAATA', 'AAATAATTA', 'AAATAATAA', 'AAATAAAAA', 'AAATAAATA', 'AAAAAATTA'}
```

---

To break that down a little further, since it looks a bit like line noise if you aren't familiar with the functions in question...

Here's the `zip` that turns our two strings into an iteration of pairs (wrapping it in a list comprehension for easy printing, but we'll remove that in the next stage):

```
>>> [t for t in zip(Ref, Test)]
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'A')]
```

The `product` function takes an arbitrary number of iterables as arguments; we want to feed it all of our 2-tuples as separate arguments using `*`:

```
>>> [t for t in product(*zip(Ref, Test))]
[('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ... (a whole lot of tuples)
```

Use `join` to turn those tuples back into strings:

```
>> [''.join(t) for t in product(*zip(Ref, Test))]
['AAAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAATA', 'AAAAAAATA', ... (still a whole lot of strings)
```

And by making this a set comprehension (`{}`) instead of a list comprehension (`[]`), we get just the unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (as `.product` will make more copies of equal strings in your case), You can use `recursion` and [`generators`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and implement your own solution. My inclination is that this should be more performant for that reason if these sequences are very large. However, if not then the `itertools` solution is better.

```
def take_some(to: str, from_: str):
     assert len(to) == len(from_)  # your precondition
     if to == from_:  # no-more left to check ('' == '') in worst case
         yield from_
         return
     for i, (l, r) in enumerate(zip(to, from_)):
          if l != r:
               # do not take the character
               rest = take_some(to[i+1:], from_[i+1:])
               for res in rest:
                   yield to[:i+1] + res
                   yield to[:i] + r + res
               return
```

Giving

```
In [2]: list(take_some("AAAAAAAAA", "AAATAATTA"))                                     
['AAAAAAAAA',
 'AAATAAAAA',
 'AAAAAATAA',
 'AAATAATAA',
 'AAAAAAATA',
 'AAATAAATA',
 'AAAAAATTA',
 'AAATAATTA']
```

Note that this does contain the original `Ref` string, you can delete it out of the result at the end if you really mean not to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations` can be used to generate the position combinations, you can control the tuple size at the second argument of `itertools.combinations`

```
import itertools

REF = "AAAAAAAAA"
poses =(3,6,7)
for i in range(1, len(poses) + 1):
    tmp = itertools.combinations(poses, i)
    for j in tmp:
        result = REF
        print(j)
        for k in j:
            result = result[:k]+'T' + result[k+1:]
        print(result)
```

Result:

```
(3,)
AAATAAAAA
(6,)
AAAAAATAA
(7,)
AAAAAAATA
(3, 6)
AAATAATAA
(3, 7)
AAATAAATA
(6, 7)
AAAAAATTA
(3, 6, 7)
AAATAATTA
```